# How to modify the class attribute in ng-repeat module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

Here is my plunker.[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kkUIxouny9ZREUylgZEF?p=info)
I'm a newer to AngularJS and I want to modify the class style of the star to show if it's marked.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 cell-project" ng-repeat="project in projects">
              <div class="panel panel-primary panel-project">
                  <div class="panel-heading" ng-switch="project.PermissionStatus">
                      <span ng-bind="project.ProjectName"></span>
                      <i class="fa fa-gear i-setup" ng-switch-when="1"></i>
                      <div ng-switch-when="0" ng-switch="project.CollectionStatus">
                          <i class="fa fa-star i-setup" ng-switch-when="1" ng-click="updateCol(0)"></i>
                          <i class="fa fa-star-o i-setup" ng-switch-when="0" ng-click="updateCol(1)"></i>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the updateCol function:

```
$scope.updateCol = function(collectionStatus){
if (1 === collectionStatus) {
    console.log("marked");
    //$(this).removeClass("fa fa-star-o i-setup ng-scope");
    //$(this).addClass("fa fa-star i-setup ng-scope");
    //do something to change its class from "fa-star-o" to "fa-star"
 }
else if (0 === collectionStatus) {
    console.log("unmarked");
    //do something to change its class from "fa-star" to "fa-star-o"
}};
```

How to solve this? When I use id selector, all the  classes are changed, not the one that I want to modify. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the click handler just update the value of `CollectionStatus`

```
<i class="fa fa-star i-setup" ng-switch-when="1" ng-click="project.CollectionStatus = 0"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star-o i-setup" ng-switch-when="0" ng-click="project.CollectionStatus = 1"></i>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sTuLKKDQDfQMJgz2UwJq?p=preview)

---

Using ng-class

```
<div class="panel-heading" ng-switch="project.PermissionStatus">
    <span ng-bind="project.ProjectName"></span>
    <i class="fa fa-gear i-setup" ng-switch-when="1"></i>
    <i class="fa i-setup" ng-class="{'fa-star': project.CollectionStatus == 1,  'fa-star-o': project.CollectionStatus == 0 }" ng-click="updateStatus(project)"></i>
</div>
```

then

```
  $scope.updateStatus = function(project){
    project.CollectionStatus = project.CollectionStatus == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    //do your ajax here
    if (1 === project.CollectionStatus) {
        console.log("marked");
        //$(this).removeClass("fa fa-star-o i-setup ng-scope");
        //$(this).addClass("fa fa-star i-setup ng-scope");
        //do something to change its class from "fa-star-o" to "fa-star"
     }
    else if (0 === project.CollectionStatus) {
        console.log("unmarked");
        //do something to change its class from "fa-star" to "fa-star-o"
    }
  };
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m6KSF1MBKPb43nhNrkpK?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much! When clicking this <i>, I also want to send a ajax to tell the server that the CollectingStatus is changed as well as change its class, so I add a function here. Can you tell me how to solve this in function?

Comment: Just a little different from the result that I hope: when the PermissionStatus = 1, I only want the fa-gear class; when the Permission Status = 0, the fa-star class is shown. That's why I use the second ng-switch.

Answer (score 0):

`1 === collectionStatus` is not equal to `true === collectionStatus`, so you should use `1 == collectionStatus` or simply `collectionStatus`

```
$scope.updateCol = function(collectionStatus){
if (collectionStatus) {
    console.log("marked");
    //$(this).removeClass("fa fa-star-o i-setup ng-scope");
    //$(this).addClass("fa fa-star i-setup ng-scope");
    //do something to change its class from "fa-star-o" to "fa-star"
 }
else{
    console.log("unmarked");
    //do something to change its class from "fa-star" to "fa-star-o"
}};
```